# how to loop animation keying

Tags: animation

When creating a loop animation, is there any way to automatically link inverted copies or copies of keyframes?

When creating a looping animation such as a walk
For a simple example

(1) Create the following three keyframes

1. right foot forward / left foot backward
2. right foot in the center / left foot in the center
3. right foot back / left foot forward

(2) Invert and copy (1) to the subsequent frames

(3) Further, the first keyframe must be copied last for interpolation.

Each time (1) is modified, (2) and (3) must be repeated, which is very complicated.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I liked the question and hoped it would be supported by Blender...and it worked!

So I made this very perfect walk animation with my very perfect model - I hope you won't be too jealous:

[image]

**Note**: I just tried this out with Bone rotation set to xyz euler. I have no idea whether this works with Quaternion too.

Select all keyframes on frame 1 in pose mode in graph editor and move your timeline to your "middle" which means: to the 0 rotation for the legs.

So it should look like this:

[image]

Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy your keyframes.

Now press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> -> by times over current frame

[image]

result:

[image]

Now press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> -> by values over zero value

[image]

result:

[image]

Now press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> again (to paste your saved keyframes)

result:

[image]

animation result:

[image]

Now select all and move timeline like this:

[image]

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (copy keyframes)
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> -> mirror over current frame

[image]

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> (paste)

[image]

result:

[image]

now press <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> -> make cyclic

[image]

[image]

result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I had never used a mirror copy before and learned a lot. But this is just copy/paste and if I change one it will not be reflected in the other. What I wanted to know is how to link one to the other so that when one is changed, the other is mirrored. Maybe this is not possible in blender.

Comment: nope, it don't think that is possible. Maybe some add-on can do that, but i am not aware of that.

Comment: and please edit your question and add to it, that you want a procedural solution, thanks